# Return list class type from private class?

Tags: c#

I want return a list with a private class type. Suppose this situation:

```
class Article_GET
{
    public class Article
    {
         public string name {get; set;}
         public string description {get;set;}
    }
}
```

Now I've another file with the class Article, in this class I have the method `GetArticles()` that create a list of Article accessing to the `Article` class available in `Article_GET`. Check:

```
public static List<Article_GET.Article> GetArticles()
{
     return new Article_GET().GetArticle(); //Method in Article_GET
}
```

The class Article that call `Article_GET().GetArticle();` is a dll wrapper. Now there is a problem. How you can see `class Article_GET` is private so I got this error:

> Inconsistent accessibility: return type List List GET.List>is less accessible than the 'List.GetList (string method)' Article

'cause should be `public class Article_GET`. But I want that this class must use only internally in the dll assembly.  I tried to put `internal` but same problem, I can't return a specific list  of `Article_GET.Article` from a private / internal class to a public method.

How can I fix this?

**UPDATE (new structure suggested):**

```
namespace MyCompany.Product.Article.GET.Article
{
    internal class Article
    {
        public string name {get;set;}
        public string description {get;set;}
    }

    class Article_GET
    {
        public class RootObject
        {
            public List<Article> article { get; set; }
        }

        public List<Article> GetArticle()
        {   
            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>("json");
            return obj.article;
        }
    }
}
```

and the wrapper:

```
namespace MyCompany.Product.Article
{
    public class Article
    {
        public static List<GET.Article.Article> GetArticles()
        {
            return new Article_GET().GetArticle();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You **can return internal class** to the public method in the same assembly. You **can't return it from a public method of a public class**. So you should rather [map that internal class to some public class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118085/best-practices-for-mapping-one-object-to-another) and return that public one instead. And please, post [the actual code that fails](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - it will allow to avoid of lot of guessing on our part and improve the chances of getting solid answers on yours.

Comment: @EugenePodskal If I declared `internal class Article_GET` I get inconsistent accessibility on the public method. Maybe I misunderstood what do you mean? I'll take a look to the example that you have linked.

Comment: I mean that `GetArticles` is a public method in a public class. While `Article_GET.Article` is an internal class (its outer "parent" class is internal). And you try to return `Article_GET.Article` from your public `GetArticles` method. You probably meant to return some `Article_PubliclyVisible.Article` that is a  public class completely separate from the  `Article_GET.Article` , if I understand you right.

Comment: @EugenePodskal okay now is clear, I'll try to fix the cast conversion but apparently the inconsistence error is disapparead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move `Article` outside of class `Article_GET`

```
internal class Article_GET
{
}

public class Article
{
     public string name {get; set;}
     public string description {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Oh I didn't thought this. But now I get `Implicit cast from System.Collections.Generic.List<Article.Get.Article.Article> in System.Collections.Generic.List<Article.Get.Article.Article_GET.Article>` in `public static List<Article> GetArticles() `

Comment: @Dillinger Remove the Article_GET prefix from Article, because it is no longer a nested class and the fully qualified type name is different

Comment: I understood the error, it's the method `public List<Article> GetArticle` available in the class `Article_GET`, now the inconsistence error is come back

Comment: Can you add your code to the question? Is the Article class directly in the namespace and where is the GetArticle method?

Comment: @Dillinger You can't have a class name the same as the namespace name. Change `Article` in the namespace to something else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110072/discussion-between-dillinger-and-glen-thomas).