# Assign C# variable to another variable, avar.GiveTo(something.else)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This may seem like a dumb question but I have reasons to want to copy a bunch of properties in one object A into another B, where A is a subset of B.
This means when writing out the code in C#, it's difficult to be sure I have actually copied everything off A.

`A.` <=Intellisense gives me everything in A, which I don't care about.

`B.` <=great but I cannot finish typing in such a way that it will end up like this:
A.prop = B.similarProp

So it's a picky thing, I just want to know how to write an extension method that will do this (I have literally no idea.)

B.something.GiveTo(A.somethingelse)

I DONT WANT TO USE AUTOMAPPER because it will error since B is a SUPERSET of A in this case.

I'm not trying to ask how to map properties of an object. I'm asking how to write something that will let me type `A.propa.ExtensionMethodGiveTo(b.propa)`

Comment: Have you tried something, if so post your in-progress code

Comment: You want to copy values of similar attributes of A to B?

Comment: @Prajwal Yes the question says so.

Comment: I literally have no idea that's why I'm posting

Comment: Not all attributes, that's for AutoMapper. I want to make typing these things easier. For example when updating an entity from an InputDto, that means I have to write out every map manually unless I want error from AutoMapper. I don't mind doing it, but it just takes ages

Comment: Can be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118085/best-practices-for-mapping-one-object-to-another (or any other "map properties of type A to B" question)...

Comment: I'm not trying to ask how to map properties of an object. I'm asking how to write something that will let me type `A.propa.giveto.(b.propa)`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of properties in type `A`. ([How to get the list of properties of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737151/how-to-get-the-list-of-properties-of-a-class))

Create a generalised method to type `A` or `B`. ([Generic Methods (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx))

Then compare the property type and name, if both are same, then you can assign that to passed instance.

Comment: I did. So far, I'm sticking with the answer. If this is not what you expected, then please edit your question and explain a bit more. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask