# Mapping one model to another

Tags: c#, casting, model, mapping

I have two models, one of which I process and return it to a view and then from the view I send it to a controller. In the controller, I need to send it to a stored procedure but the stored procedure expects a model with different property names.
Here is my model:

```
public class Operator
    {
        public int OPERATOR_OBJECTID { get; set; }

        public string SETTLEMENT_OBJECTID { get; set; }

        public string TECHNOLOGY_OBJECTID { get; set; }
    }
```

and here is the model the stored procedure expects

```
public class UploadModel
    {
        public int OPERATOR_OBJECTID { get; set; }
        public string SETTLEMENT_CODE { get; set; }
        public string TECHNOLOGY_CODE { get; set; }
    }
```

Since I send the properties from `Operator`, like `SETTLEMENT_OBJECTID` but it expects `SETTLEMENT_CODE` it throws an exception. Can I somehow map the properties from one model to another or can I cast one model to another? What would be a good solution here?

Comment: You can use automapper. See following link https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/

Comment: You can also see an example of using AutoMapper [Simple Automapper Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20635534/simple-automapper-example)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best Practices for mapping one object to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118085/best-practices-for-mapping-one-object-to-another)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use the automapper library and configure as such:

```
var mapConfig = new MapperConfiguration(
   cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Operator, UploadModel>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.SETTLEMENT_CODE, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SETTLEMENT_OBJECTID))
      .ForMember(dest => dest.TECHNOLOGY_CODE, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.TECHNOLOGY_OBJECTID))
);
```

Check here the getting started guide: https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html

You can also define an explicit operator to be able to cast from one class to the other: https://www.dotnetperls.com/explicit